# Applescript creating subfolder

Tags: applescript, workflow

Good day,

I have used multiple sources to crete a workflow for creating folder structure which creates sub folders.  The problem i am having is with the section that creates sub-folders under 'MyCompany" subfolder.

```
    tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    set Customer to text returned of (display dialog "Customer Name:" default answer "Customer")
    set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
    set incomingDate to (current date)
    set yr to year of incomingDate as text
    set mo to (month of incomingDate as number) as text
    if ((length of mo) = 1) then
        set mo to "0" & mo
    end if
    set dy to day of incomingDate as text
    if ((length of dy) = 1) then
        set dy to "0" & dy
    end if
    set newfoldername to mo & dy & yr & "-" & JobName
    set customer2 to Customer & "-" & JobName
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Caps"}
    set doc to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Document"}
    make new folder at doc with properties {name:"Customer"}
    make new folder at doc with properties {name:"Lic"}
    make new folder at doc with properties {name:"Deliverable"}
    make new folder at doc with properties {name:"Mfg"}
    make new folder at doc with properties {name:"Validation"}
    set mdc to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"MyCompany"}
    make new folder at mdc with properties {name:"Quotes"}
    make new folder at mdc with properties {name:"SoW"}
    make new folder at mdc with properties {name:"Private"}
    set cfg to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Config"}
    make new folder at cfg with properties {name:"Sites"}
    make new folder at cfg with properties {name:"Worksheet"}
    make new folder at cfg with properties {name:"Backups"}
    make new folder at cfg with properties {name:"Logs"}
    set diag to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Diagrams"}
    make new folder at diag with properties {name:"Screenshots"}
    make new folder at diag with properties {name:"Visio"}
    make new folder at diag with properties {name:"Logos"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Scripts"}

end tell

tell application id "com.evernote.Evernote"
    create note with text "via Apple WorkFlow" title customer2 notebook "Inbox"
end tell
```

What I would like to have is:

mmddyy-%currenttime%-JobName
   Document 
      MyCompany
          Quotes
          SoW
          Private

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What results are you getting that don't give you those three folders inside the MyCompany folder?

Comment: The issue is that it creates the MyCompany Folder under .Documents, but it does NOT create the Sub Folders under that location.  It creates a new folder named 'MyCompany' and then creates the sub folder under THAT folder

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but it worked for me:

```
-- Sets up the JobName, CustomerName and location by asking the user

set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
set Customer to text returned of (display dialog "Customer Name:" default answer "Customer")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
```

-- Sets up the date variables

```
set incomingDate to (current date)
set yr to year of incomingDate as text
set mo to (month of incomingDate as number) as text
if ((length of mo) = 1) then
set mo to "0" & mo
end if
set dy to day of incomingDate as text
if ((length of dy) = 1) then
set dy to "0" & dy
end if
```

-- Sets the filename to be used concatinated with date

```
set newfoldername to mo & dy & yr & "-" & JobName
set customer2 to Customer & "-" & JobName

tell application "Finder"

--Parent Directory Structure

set dir_1 to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
set dir_2 to make new folder at dir_1 with properties {name:"Caps"}
set dir_3 to make new folder at dir_1 with properties {name:"Configs"}
set dir_4 to make new folder at dir_1 with properties {name:"Diagrams"}
set dir_5 to make new folder at dir_1 with properties {name:"Documents"}
set dir_6 to make new folder at dir_1 with properties {name:"Scripts"}

-- Sub-Folder structure

set sub_3_1 to make new folder at dir_3 with properties {name:"Backups"}
set sub_3_2 to make new folder at dir_3 with properties {name:"Logs"}
set sub_3_3 to make new folder at dir_3 with properties {name:"Sites"}
set sub_3_4 to make new folder at dir_3 with properties {name:"Worksheets"}

set sub_4_1 to make new folder at dir_4 with properties {name:"Logos"}
set sub_4_2 to make new folder at dir_4 with properties {name:"Screenshots"}
set sub_4_3 to make new folder at dir_4 with properties {name:"Network Diagrams"}


set sub_5_1 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"Customer"}
set sub_5_2 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"Deliverable"}
set sub_5_3 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"License"}
set sub_5_4 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"Certificates"}
set sub_5_5 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"MyCompany"}
set sub_5_6 to make new folder at dir_5 with properties {name:"Validation"}

-- Creates sub-folders under \MyCompany

set sub2_5_1 to make new folder at sub_5_5 with properties {name:"BoMs"}
set sub2_5_2 to make new folder at sub_5_5 with properties {name:"Quotes"}
set sub2_5_3 to make new folder at sub_5_5 with properties {name:"Private"}
set sub2_5_4 to make new folder at sub_5_5 with properties {name:"SoW"}

-- Set variable to be used by Evernote

    set custfldr to the loc as text 
end tell
tell application "Finder"
set the clipboard to the loc as text
end tell

tell application id "com.evernote.Evernote"
create note with text custfldr title customer2 notebook "Inbox"
end tell
```

This gives me the desired outcome.